# JVM Crash with 1.6_07

Tags: jvm

```
Below issue occurs with 1.6_07 version and it is not reproducible. Anyone aware of this? This is not a SIGSEGV crash, with "fatal error" has occurred or "out of memory" error. It says, "unexpected error". Appreciate if someone can please comment.

FULL PRODUCT VERSION :
1.6.0_07_x64

A DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM :
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000002a95c48a27, pid=29187, tid=1389758816
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x5d8a27]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# hs_err_pid29187.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#


ERROR MESSAGES/STACK TRACES THAT OCCUR :
First Occurrence:-

#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000002a958d1cd8, pid=19203, tid=1086544224
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x261cd8]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http ://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000002b5f7c9000):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000] [id=19366]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=128 (), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000014, RBX=0x4300000000000000, RCX=0x0000000000000001, RDX=0x0000000040c34c50
RSP=0x0000000040c34c50, RBP=0x0000000040c34d20, RSI=0x0000002b2f82c4c8, RDI=0x0000002b2f82c4b1
R8 =0x0000002b61b32b10, R9 =0x0000002a95eacf20, R10=0x000000000001fff9, R11=0x0000000000000015
R12=0x0000000000000014, R13=0x0000000040c34de0, R14=0x0000002b2f82c4c8, R15=0x0000000040c34c50
RIP=0x0000002a958d1cd8, EFL=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000000, ERR=0x0000000000000000
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000d

  Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000040c34c50)
0x0000000040c34c50:   0000002a95eacbf0 0000002b5f817d20
0x0000000040c34c60:   0000002b5f7c7000 0000002aa3c80000
0x0000000040c34c70:   00000000175b4000 0000002b14a80038
0x0000000040c34c80:   000000000001fff9 0000002b5f7c7160
0x0000000040c34c90:   0000002b5f7ca260 0000002b5f7c72a0
0x0000000040c34ca0:   0000002b5f7c7360 0000002b14aff1b0
0x0000000040c34cb0:   0000000040d35d98 0000000040c34de0
0x0000000040c34cc0:   0000000040c34d00 0000002a95b5d0cf
0x0000000040c34cd0:   0000002b14a80038 000000000001fff9
0x0000000040c34ce0:   0000000040c34de0 0000002a95b742c2
0x0000000040c34cf0:   0000000000000000 0000000040c34de0
0x0000000040c34d00:   0000002b14add0d8 000000000e1e0000
0x0000000040c34d10:   0000002b5f7c71e8 0000000040c34de0
0x0000000040c34d20:   0000000040c34d40 0000002a958d1a73
0x0000000040c34d30:   000000000e1cba1b 00000000003872e8
0x0000000040c34d40:   0000000040c34d80 0000002a95841690
0x0000000040c34d50:   0000000000387801 0000002aa3c80000
0x0000000040c34d60:   000000000e1e0000 0000002b5f12b8b0
0x0000000040c34d70:   0000000040d35d50 0000000000020000
0x0000000040c34d80:   0000000040c34ec0 0000002a958c8e2f
0x0000000040c34d90:   0000002a95ec6500 0000002b5f7ca260
0x0000000040c34da0:   0000000000000008 0000002b5f7c7000
0x0000000040c34db0:   0000000040c34de0 0000000040c34e60
0x0000000040c34dc0:   0000000040c34e70 0000000040c34e80
0x0000000040c34dd0:   0000002b5f12b918 0000070e00000000
0x0000000040c34de0:   0000002a95eac510 0000002b5f7c7000
0x0000000040c34df0:   0000002aa3c80000 00000000175b4000
0x0000000040c34e00:   0000002b14a80038 000000000001fff9
0x0000000040c34e10:   0000002b5f7c7160 0000002b5f7c7200
0x0000000040c34e20:   0000002b5f7ca260 0000002b5f7c72a0
0x0000000040c34e30:   0000002b5f7c7360 0000000095c9ae01
0x0000000040c34e40:   0000002b14aff1b0 0000002b14a80038

Instructions: (pc=0x0000002a958d1cd8)
0x0000002a958d1cc8:   56 08 4c 89 f6 48 8b 5a 10 48 8d 7a 10 4c 89 fa
0x0000002a958d1cd8:   ff 93 50  customer  00 00 4c 8b 0d ab 52 6d 00 41 8b 01

Stack: [0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000],  sp=0x0000000040c34c50,  free space=1061075k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x261cd8]
V  [libjvm.so+0x261a73]
V  [libjvm.so+0x1d1690]
V  [libjvm.so+0x258e2f]
V  [libjvm.so+0x2588d9]
V  [libjvm.so+0x67b967]
V  [libjvm.so+0x679024]
V  [libjvm.so+0x50630a]
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x6137]
C  0x0000000000000000

SECOND OCCURRENCE

#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000002a95c48a27, pid=29187, tid=1389758816
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x5d8a27]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http ://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000002b69330c00):  JavaThread "AdminThread" [_thread_in_vm, id=27139, stack(0x0000000052c60000,0x0000000052d61000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=128 (), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000002b8159ecf0, RBX=0x0000002b69330c00, RCX=0x0000002b8159f0d8, RDX=0x0000002b8159ed00
RSP=0x0000000052d5f650, RBP=0x0000000052d5f660, RSI=0x0000002b0bda7530, RDI=0x010000002b597c0d
R8 =0x0000002b692e39a0, R9 =0x0000000000006a03, R10=0x0000002a95fb8f80, R11=0x0000000052d5f740
R12=0x0000002b0bda8588, R13=0x0000000052d5f6b0, R14=0x0000000052d5f788, R15=0x0000002b69330c00
RIP=0x0000002a95c48a27, EFL=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x000000000000f358, ERR=0x0000000000000000
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000d

  Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000052d5f650)
0x0000000052d5f650:   0000002b69330c00 0000002b0bda8588
0x0000000052d5f660:   0000000052d5f670 0000002a95ae4a9d
0x0000000052d5f670:   0000000052d5f6e0 0000002a9598f896
0x0000000052d5f680:   0000002b692e39a0 0000002b8159ecf0
0x0000000052d5f690:   0000002b8159ed00 0000002b8159f0d8
0x0000000052d5f6a0:   0000002b69330c00 0000002a958e90dc
0x0000000052d5f6b0:   0000002b69330c00 0000002b0bda8588
0x0000000052d5f6c0:   0000002b69330c00 0000002b0bda0eb1
0x0000000052d5f6d0:   0000002b0bda8588 0000002b5b376ad5
0x0000000052d5f6e0:   0000000052d5f740 0000002a9656c56f
0x0000000052d5f6f0:   0000002a96565df0 0000002a9656c53b
0x0000000052d5f700:   0000000052d5f700 0000002b5b376ad5
0x0000000052d5f710:   0000000052d5f788 0000002b5b3f0378
0x0000000052d5f720:   0000002b5b932df0 0000002b5b376c48
0x0000000052d5f730:   0000000000000000 0000000052d5f780
0x0000000052d5f740:   0000000052d5f7d8 0000002a96563162
0x0000000052d5f750:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000052d5f760:   0000000000000000 0000002a9cfe8700
0x0000000052d5f770:   0000002a9cfe8650 0000002a9cfe1a10
0x0000000052d5f780:   0000000000000000 0000002ae0506818
0x0000000052d5f790:   0000002ae0506818 0000000052d5f798
0x0000000052d5f7a0:   0000002b5a6b4e0c 0000000052d5f828
0x0000000052d5f7b0:   0000002b5a6b5ba8 0000000000000000
0x0000000052d5f7c0:   0000002b5a6b5550 0000000052d5f788
0x0000000052d5f7d0:   0000000052d5f818 0000000052d5f870
0x0000000052d5f7e0:   0000002a96563162 0000002ae0506818
0x0000000052d5f7f0:   0000002a9cfe19e8 0000002a9cfe1990
0x0000000052d5f800:   0000002a9cfe1938 0000002a9cfc90a0
0x0000000052d5f810:   0000002a9cfc8448 0000002a9cfc9070
0x0000000052d5f820:   0000002a9cfc8e70 0000002abc541170
0x0000000052d5f830:   0000000052d5f830 0000002b59971962
0x0000000052d5f840:   0000000052d5f898 0000002b59f5dee8

Instructions: (pc=0x0000002a95c48a27)
0x0000002a95c48a17:   89 f0 eb ea 90 66 66 66 90 55 48 89 e5 41 54 53
0x0000002a95c48a27:   0f b7 57 10 48 89 fb 44 8d 62 01 49 63 fc e8 06

Stack: [0x0000000052c60000,0x0000000052d61000],  sp=0x0000000052d5f650,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x5d8a27]
V  [libjvm.so+0x474a9d]
V  [libjvm.so+0x31f896]
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::StubRoutines (1)
V  [libjvm.so+0x33ffed]
V  [libjvm.so+0x505659]
V  [libjvm.so+0x33f8d8]
V  [libjvm.so+0x33f97b]
V  [libjvm.so+0x3c4a93]
V  [libjvm.so+0x624ac1]
V  [libjvm.so+0x50630a]
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x6137]
C  0x0000000000000000

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::StubRoutines (1)
```

Comment: I'd check the Oracle/Sun bug database before I did anything else.  You are not alone: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jvm+1.6_07+crash+libjvm.so&safe=active and http://search.oracle.com/search/search?group=Sun+Defects&site=bugs.sun.com&q=10.0-b23+mixed+mode+linux-amd64+libjvm.so

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely need to use such an old version?

There have been 21 updates since then with major performance and security fixes.

I work in a pretty conservative environment but we have updated on a regular basis and are currently on 1.60_26.

Chances are that a fix will have been made in later versions.